# Theorem 6.15 in Gilbarg & Trudinger's book

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I meet a problem in Theorem 6.15. of Gilbarg & Trudinger's book.

Theorem 6.15.  Let $L=a^{ij}D_{ij}+b^iD_i+c$ be strictly elliptic with coefficients in $C^{\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$ in a $C^{2,\alpha}$ domain $\Omega$. Then either:(a) the homogeneous problem, $Lu=0$ in $\Omega$,$u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ has only trivial solution, in which case the inhomogeneous problem $Lu=f$ in $\Omega$, $u=\varphi$ in $\partial \Omega$, has a unique $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$ solution for all $f \in C^{\alpha}(\overline \Omega), \varphi \in C^{2,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$;or (b) the homogeneous problem has nontrivial solutions, which form a finite dimensional subspace of $C^{2,\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$.

Proof. We have seen that under the stated assumptions concerning $f$ and $\varphi$ the inhomogeneous problem, $Lu=f$ in $\Omega \cdots,$ Furthermore, the inverse mapping $L_{\sigma}^{-1}$, by estimate (6.36) and Theorem 3.7, is a compact mapping from $C^{\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$ into $C^{\alpha}(\overline \Omega)$.$\cdots$

> While inequality 6.36 is $$ |u|_{2,\alpha;\Omega}\leq C(|u|_{0;\Omega}+|\varphi|_{2,\alpha;\Omega}+|f|_{0,\alpha;\Omega})$$ where $C=C(n,\alpha,\lambda,\Lambda,\Omega)$

> Theorem 3.7.   Let $Lu=f$ in a bounded domain $\Omega$, where $L$ is a elliptic , $c\leq 0$ and $u\in C^0(\overline \Omega)\cap C^2(\Omega)$. Then $$\sup_{\Omega}|u|\leq \sup_{\partial \Omega}|u|+C\sup_{\Omega}(|f|/\lambda)$$ where $C$ is a constant depending only on diam$\Omega$ and $\beta=sup |b|/\lambda$. In particular, if $\Omega$ lies between two parallel planes a distance $d$ apart, then the above inequality is satisfied with $C=e^{(\beta+1)d}-1$.

Why  $L_{\sigma}^{-1}$ is a compact operator? It is diffcult for me. Could someone give me some hints(I cannot work it out by the definition of compact operator)? Thank you!

Comment: People who don't have this book can't see what estimate (6.36) and Theorem 3.7 are, which are apparently the basis for $L_\sigma^{-1}$ being compact.  Perhaps you could fill in the missing details, ideally by precising the ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I have typed it again.